# how to embed video in laravel code

Tags: php, mysql, video, embed, laravel

I am working on a project in which I store youtube video links in a database and then I retrieve those links and using blade template engine i try to embed them into page. I use a loop to put videos in a page. For some reason I'm not getting any video in the browser. It is covering the mentioned space but not rendering anything. I'm using laravel 3. Here's couple of code snippets, if they help.

---

This is the index.blade.php

```
@layout('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@foreach ($videos as $video)
    <h4>{{ $video->title }}</h4>
    <br>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="{{ $video->link }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
@endforeach

@endsection
```

---

The $videos variable is passed from controller.

```
class Videos_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
public $restful = true;

public function get_index()
{
    $videos = DB::table('videos')->get();
    return View::make('videos.index')
        ->with('title', 'Videos')
        ->with('videos', $videos);
}
}
```

---

All i get is a blank page. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. I'm using twitter bootstrap for css prototyping. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's how master.blade.php's 'head' looks like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ $title }} </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
    {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css') }}
</head>
```

---

This is what comes up in firefox when I inspect element.

```
<div class="media">

<div class="media-body">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""   src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iBm60uJXvs">
        #document
            <html>
                <head></head>
                <body></body>
            </html>
    </iframe>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the `blank page`'s source code? Is it generating the iFrames? If so, did you check that the links work in an browser?

Comment: It does generate the iframes and the links does work in the browser.

Comment: @Xk0nSid : I am facing the same issue . did you manage to find a solution. Even my page is rendered properly , with the correct links but the video is not getting displayed.

Comment: @Gagan Sorry. Couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately , I did manage to find a solution to my problem. Hopefully it should help you as well . Use the url that is present in the embed statement. so for example if you goto youtube and click on the embed link of **[this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BstTBw6BLrE)** video  you would get this

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/BstTBw6BLrE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

now use the url that is present in the src tag. This works with other video hosting services, like VEVO as well.

Hope it helps..

Comment: just to add one more thing: the resultant url must begin with http:// and then you can append the url that you get from the src tag

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking to Embed Videos in Laravel, have a look at [KaneCohen/embed](https://github.com/KaneCohen/embed). It's works great with Youtube or Vimeo (haven't tried other sources), and you don't have to mess with any logic. Simply install (installation guide in [documentation](https://github.com/KaneCohen/embed#installation)) and:

```
@foreach ($videos as $video)
    <h4>{{ $video->title }}</h4>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            {!! Embed::make($video->link)->parseUrl()->getIframe() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Don't forget to set up the alias in you `config/app.php`

Comment: that helped, Thanks. Is there anyway available to get thumbnail of the video thru this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but the console catch this error:

> Refused to display 'URL' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I look for it here and i found this post

[Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin)

and that work for me.

You should try this

```
@layout('layouts.master')

@section('content')

@foreach ($videos as $video)
    <h4>{{ $video->title }}</h4>
    <br>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src={{ $video->link + "&output=embed" }} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
@endforeach

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple blade tag in the view

**{!! $url !!}** THIS WILL RENDER THE VIDEO

instead of

{{ $url }} THIS WILL WRITE AS A STRING (in a input for example)

Answer (score 0):

The [laravel-embed package](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-embed) can help by giving you the ability to embed a YouTube video (and others) using a blade component:

```html
<x-embed url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0" />
```

You simply pass the public URL of the video into the url attribute and the package will handle the rest.

Additionally there are validation rules for all the services supported by the package (it's not just YouTube) and it's responsive out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

how does your 'layouts.master' looks like?
any html source code in your browser?
have a look: your 'index.blade.php' should be encoded in UTF-8 WITHOUT 'BOM' (in your editor)!!

'@layout('layouts.master')' has to be the very first (same issue to me yesterday in L4).

Comment: this is not an answer for this question .. plzz post this as a comment

Comment: "@layouts('layouts.master')" is the first thing.
I've added the master.blade.php's '<head>' content in the question.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use {{}} instead of this use {!!  !!}

For example :

```html
{!! $video->link !!}
```

Comment: that is not for embed video.