# Laravel 4 refuses to load iframe due to 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, http-headers, same-origin-policy

I am building a chrome extension in which I am showing an iframe on a popup from the Gmail home page. As Gmail home page is in HTTPS , my iframe should also be in https. I configured apache2 by enabling mod_ssl and got HTTPS working on apache2. I made a native PHP page and tried to show that on the frame which is on Gmail page. I had no problems it was loading the page from localhost. But when I wanted to use a Laravel backend, it showed me error.

`Refused to display 'https://localhost/laravel/laravel/public/index.php/chromelogin' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Any Suggestions??

Comment: Check out this solution and see if it works - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add following line in your `bootstrap/start.php` file:

```
$app->forgetMiddleware('Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard');
```

Comment: Is there also a solution for laravel 5?

Comment: No, it's been removed AFAIK but I'll look the source again or find another way because I need it too :-)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, forgot to check it but now I'll check it again, thanks for the reminder @Jarco :-)

Comment: I myself fixed it by forcing nginx to set the header

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service provider and put this in the register() function

```
$this->app->forgetMiddleware('Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard');
```

This way you can put in logic if you don't want to disable it for your whole application.

Answer (score 1):

### This is removed since 4.2

> Removing this by default in 4.2. Should be in an after filter - will leave FrameGuard class so people can add the middleware manually if they want.
>
> -- [Taylor Otwell](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1725#issuecomment-33535578)

You can confirm this If you look at the source code or search your project folder so you can see that the class is still under `Illuminate\Http\Middleware` but the only reference to it is in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Optimize/config.php`:

```
$basePath.'/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/FrameGuard.php',
```