# Embedding Liferay site as iframe is not working on external site

Tags: iframe, liferay, liferay-6

I have got a Liferay page which has Portlet. I tried to embed this page as an iframe in external site which is not in Liferay but it is giving the error in console as:

> Refused to display 'https://example.com' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

I am using html iframe tag like below to embed it:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="400" src="https://example.com" style="border:0" width="500"></iframe>
```

Following this thread I tried putting "&output=embed" at end of the URL but it didn't work: [Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin)

I am not sure whether I need to change setting or any code on Liferay side to make it work. Any idea what is causing this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`X-Frame-options` response header is used to prevent [clickjacking](http://javascript.info/tutorial/clickjacking#x-frame-options). All the requests in Liferay by default has this header set to `DENY` for all external URLs i.e. Liferay site cannot be iFramed or embedded in an iframe from any other site other than the Liferay site with the same domain.

Assuming you are using Liferay Version 6.2.x, you can have two approaches to allow Liferay to be iFramed:

#### Approach-I

Disable the property [`http.header.secure.x.frame.options`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/system.properties#L217) to portal-ext.properties:

```
http.header.secure.x.frame.options=false
```

By default this is `true`.

#### Approach-II (recommended)

Add URL of the page to the property [`http.header.secure.x.frame.options.*`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/system.properties#L233) in `portal-ext.properties` so that only that particular URL can be embedded in an iframe and not the whole site.

Where **`*`** should be replaced by any positive integer value.

Some examples, please note that each URL goes in a separate property:

```
http.header.secure.x.frame.options.1=/web/guest/home
http.header.secure.x.frame.options.2=/myPortletPageToBeIframed
http.header.secure.x.frame.options.10=/group/mySite/MyPageInIframe
```

The second approach is recommended because it only allows certain pages to be iFramed reducing the risk of clickjacking on your other pages.