# Render youtube video by url from server

Tags: angularjs

I am prety sick already with inability to just embed a youtube video by url provided from database.

I have whitelisted youtube by

```
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'https://www.youtube.com/**'
    ]);
})
```

Then in controller I fetch video data from server (database) and use `$sce` to set url to be truested

```
app.controller('videosCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) {

    $scope.video = null;
    $scope.video_url = null;

    $http.get('/side/video').success(function(data) {
        if(data.length > 0) {
            $scope.video = data[0];
            $scope.video_url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(data[0].url);
        }   
    });

}]);
```

then I render `iframe` by (jade)

```
iframe(ng-src="{{video_url2}}",width="100%",height="300",frameborder="0",allowfullscreen)
```

And in result in chrome dev console I get

```
Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WN66EpVdxsk' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

What **else** should I do to convince angular that it's ok to render videos from youtube?!

**SOLUTION:** I have found that `/watch` refuses to stream videos from different origin, but `www.youtube.com/embed/` allowes, so I just extracted video id from first url and added it to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a CORS issue to me rather than an Angular issue if I'm not mistaken but I'm not sure how to get it fixed. check these question for a similar issue

- [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)
- [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)
- [Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin)