# Error showing feed content in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I had requirements to pull feed from the TinyPulse website. I have been provided with the feed URL and I have put it that in an `<iframe>` and all of sudden after few days it showing me this error.

"Refused to display 'https://app.tinypulse.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

I have tried some options but they are not working.

[Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin)

Does someone come across this sort of issue and have any recommendation how to solve it.

Comment: Ask the tinypulse people, only they can fix this.

Comment: What code you using to get the feed?

Comment: Ah, just noticed your subject, your using an iFrame to get data,.  then don't use an iFrame, use ajax instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apache option for this been turn ON on the server. It was turn on in the response to the vulnerability assessments. It is to prevent "Click Jacking".