# Changing iframe src with jquery with link not with button

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which can successfully change the iframe src with a button. How can I replace the button with a textlink?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="changeframe" value="Change">

<iframe id="declinedframe" class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://forgezilla.com" height="585" width="100%" ></iframe>

// Go Last since changeframe hasn't exist yet.
<script>
  $('#changeframe').click(function () {
      $('#declinedframe').attr('src', 'http://stackoverflow.com');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _textlink_? `<SPAN>`

Comment: @Arya please check this may this will help http://stackoverflow.com/q/20498831/5635098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery or JavaScript to accomplish what you want to do, you only need HTML.

- On `<a>`nchor add `href="http://whatever.com/path/to/new/site.html"` and `target="nameOfIframe"`
- On `<iframe>` add `name="nameOfIframe"`

### Snippet

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="declinedframe">Change</a>

<iframe name="declinedframe" src="http://forgezilla.com" height="585" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

just replce

```
<input type="button" id="changeframe" value="Change">
```

with

```
<a href="#" id="changeframe">Change</a>
```

This should work