# Can't access videos from Git LFS

Tags: git, x-frame-options, git-lfs

I'm trying to use Git LFS to store some videos that I would like to access in an `iframe`. I was able to push to Github just fine, but now that I am trying to access the videos via the provided url, I get this error:

`Refused to display 'https://github.com/trentchilders/personal-site.git/info/lfs/warm_sunny1.m4v' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
 <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" 
       src="https://github.com/trentchilders/personalsite.git/info/lfs/
       warm_sunny1.m4v"></iframe>
</div>
```

I assume I need to update the configuration to allow x-frame options, but I don't see any documentation as to how to do this. Any ideas?

Edit - Turns out that Git LFS does not currently support linking.

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2477

If you found your way here because of this issue I recommend looking at Frank's comments below.

Comment: I think this maybe help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried a few of the ideas in the link you provide but to no avail. It seems like the gist of the responses in your link are for when you are trying to embed a video from YouTube. That's fine, but I was trying to host the videos in my github project using Git LFS. Of course, if I'm unable to solve this, I'll go the YouTube route.

Comment: It's not a limitation of Git LFS per se, it's that GitHub, as a company, doesn't want to be your free video host.