# how to open new link in master page in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have navigation drawer and this nav contained number of pages ..i want to add new page that will be contain another url but open in the same page with master page...is that possible ???
fev.vue file

```
<template>
<v-app>
<div class="feb">
<v-card>
<div> {{ callfeb}} </div> 
</v-card>
</div>
 </v-app>
</template>

export default {
 computed: {
     callfeb(){
        href = 'https://######', 
        target='_self'
         //window.location.href = 'https://#####'
     }
 }
}`</script>`<style></style>``
```

App.vue

```
computed: {
items() {
  return [

 {
      icon: 'link',
      text: i18n.t('H-D'),
      path: '/feb',
      perms: 'read:feb',
      show: true
    
        },
]
}
```

router.ts

```
router [
{
path: '/feb',
name: 'feb',
props: route => ({
query: route.query,
      isKiosk: route.query.kiosk,
      hash: route.hash
    }),
    component: () => 
      import(/* webpackChunkName: 'user' */ './views/feb.vue'),
    meta: { title: 'feb', requiresAuth: true }
  },
]
```

the above codes are working and open the url in same page but the master content will not show. I want the url will open in the same page with master content

Comment: You can use [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: What do you mean by url - you want to display different route of your app, or page from different domain?

Comment: url mean - "https://####.com:portnumber"

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński     i got error  Refused to display 'https://something.com:1150/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Comment: @renu check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin

Comment: yes i have already seen this ...and applied all the solution but i found same error