# content-security-policy doesn't work; I want to have my website load in an iFrame on ONE other website only

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, content-security-policy, response-headers

How do you do this? I want only one other website to be able to load my main website in an iFrame but nothing is working.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

Apparently as I understand it the protocol you set in .htaccess is this

So far I've tried:

1.

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.subdomain.co;"`

2.

`Header always set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' 'https://example.subdomain.co';"`

3.

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' 'https://example.subdomain.co';"`

None of these work. When I try to load an iframe of example.com inside https://example.subdomain.co I get the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://example.com/' in a frame because it set
> 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

And then I get more confused because apparently you can only do `DENY` and `SAMEORIGIN` with this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
> whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
> `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid
> click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.
>
> The added security is provided only if the user accessing the document
> is using a browser that supports X-Frame-Options.

The one I would have wanted is `ALLOW FROM` but

> ALLOW-FROM uri  This is an obsolete directive that no longer works in
> modern browsers. Don't use it. In supporting legacy browsers, a page
> can be displayed in a frame only on the specified origin uri. Note
> that in the legacy Firefox implementation this still suffered from the
> same problem as SAMEORIGIN did — it doesn't check the frame ancestors
> to see if they are in the same origin. The Content-Security-Policy
> HTTP header has a frame-ancestors directive which you can use instead.

It's deprecated and it doesn't work.

[Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin)

This answer doesn't help because they don't talk about what I want to do, they just explain what it is.

[How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Again, not helpful because it's explaining to OP that the header is set on the website in the iframe source.

Is there a way to set it X-Frame-Options for frame-ancestors somehow to make this work so that I can load an iframe of my website on one other specific website? Or is this not possible?

Comment: So your attempts to define a proper CSP for this were hindered by the fact that your server _also_ responds with the outdated X-FRAME-OPTIONS header - so try and _remove_ the latter (`Header unset`)

Answer (score 0):

When you set frame-ancestors correctly all browsers that understand it will disregard X-Frame-Options. This means that you can set both headers and use ALLOW-FROM as you will then server X-Frame-Options to IE and frame-ancestors to other browsers.

Have you checked if your Content-Security-Policy is present as a response header? Your first version is the most correct one, but you can drop the scheme as such: "frame-ancestors 'self' example.subdomain.co;", there should not be any single quotes around hosts in sources.